# When, how many times & how often (less's better) switch batteries to end up with 2 dead batteries?

Tags: problem-solving, word-problem

we have two mobile boxes with the same batteries inside (same capacity),
but two different micro-controllers with different power consumption, 
the batteries are hot swap-able (switchable).

One micro-controller power consumption is a constant $M$ mAh,
the second's is a constant $S$ mAh.

- in this case $M$ = 130, and $S$ = 35
- the batteries are identical

  - have capacity of $2800$mAh

Comment: I presume your consumption is milliamps, not megamps.  In that case the consumption should be mA, not Ma, though I have seen ma as well.  Either way, the consumption should be current, not current/time and not current times time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the capacity of each battery be $C$.  Your total lifetime is $\frac {2C}{M+S}$ hours from dividing total capacity by total consumption.  Swap them halfway through in time, as $\frac C{M+S}$ hours.